Is there a way for a Java application using OpenJDK 17 JRE to ignore the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable
Since I installed an application which set the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable my app stopped working, the argument passed in that env var makes my app load a java.security file which bricks my app.
Removing the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS env var isn't an option since it's needed for the above mentioned application so I was wondering if there was a way to tell my app, ignore JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS AND ONLY that env var.
Looking around the web I wasn't able to find an answer, can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.
Edit:
Firstly thank you to everyone who contributed, after some digging I found the answer.

Are you working on the app? What would you like to do to accomplish that?

I am working on it, I would like to set some sort of internal config or class variable which says, ignore the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS env var, ideally without any bash scripts or similar that temporarily unset the env var. Reason being I want both applications (mine and the one that set the env var) to run simultaneously.

When you change an environment variable in a bash script, it only affects programs you run in the bash script. (unless you source it of course.)

Of course, but a bash script isn't an option for me due to factors outside my controll hahahah. I package my app using Jar2Exe, there might be a way to disable it through that that I'm not seeing

Looks like they support that feature. https://www.jar2exe.com/features you could change the environment variable when it starts.

You could make a .bat file on windows (or .sh file on unix) to unset the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS env variable before executing your app. This will only affect the current window/process so won't unset for other open windows etc.
Alternatively, you could unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS globally and edit the script that starts the application mentioned above to set it prior to executing the app

I see, if there's no other way I'll have to do that, ideally though I would like just for my app to ignore it so I don't have to modify the system or other applications other than my own. Something like a config file in my app that just says ignore "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" env var

I don't use it, and looking at the documentation: "JNI_CreateJavaVM function (in the JNI Invocation API) prepends the value of the environment variable to the options supplied in its JavaVMInitArgs argument.". Ideally there would be a way to disable that behavior in my app

JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is a way of passing options to the jvm (eg in cases where you can't inject them into the command line call). If you don't want to pass these to your jvm, it makes sense that this env var should not be populated when you run your app.

Out of interest, what is the value of JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS that is negatively impacting your app?

The value is: -Djava.security.properties==C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\Deployment\java.security, which ensure that all java programs use that specific java.security file even if they have their own

You could unset the java.security.properties system property in the main method of your java app

@lance-java In the case of java.security.properties, I think the main will be too late.

Perhaps in the static initializer of the main class?

The key part was that my java.security file was being "overwritten/appended" by the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS env var and as it turns out there is a config inside the java.security file with the name of security.overridePropertiesFile, setting it to false prevents the java.security file from being replaced/supplanted by another one like what was happening in my case
